# helm redis-cluster error on minikube ( v1.26.0 ) in MacOS ( Monterey 12.5 )

Tags: macos, kubernetes-helm, minikube, redis-cluster

I installed redis-cluster with 6 pods(default numbers) by helm. and then, I can find error in 5 pods ( only one pod runs successful )

This is the error output from the five pods below.

```
sed: can't read /bitnami/redis/data/nodes.conf: No such file or directory
```

FYI : helm redis-cluster version : 8.2.4 , I checked not problem on minikube( v1.27.0 ) in ubuntu

Comment: This [redis-cluster helm chart, if it is from bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/redis-cluster/values.yaml#L304) has option for changing persistence storageClass value. The default storage class for minikube is [k8s.io/minikube-hostpath](https://platform9.com/blog/tutorial-dynamic-provisioning-of-persistent-storage-in-kubernetes-with-minikube/). Please check if persistent volume claims are created and bound properly.

Comment: Thank you for comment, yes I think it looks properly

`redis-data-redis-cluster-0   Bound`
`standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath`